# appcmd set ssl certificate for site

Tags: powershell, iis-7, appcmd

I am trying to give an app https bindings using one of the available certificates in IIS7 but am struggling with the syntax.

I *think* the command should look something like the following but it does not work:

```
appcmd.exe set site "mysite.com" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:www.mysite.local:mycertificatename']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I have found is to use selfssl.exe

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Resources\SelfSSL>selfssl.exe /T /N:CN=mysite.com /S:theSiteId /Q
```

I haven't found a way to do it with appcmd. The problem with this solution is it means that you have to have IIS resource kit installed on the server. Personally I think you would better off installing powershell or ruby on the server.

Depends on your ops guys I guess.